# Apache - Configuring mod_auth_sspi.so

Tags: php, apache, single-sign-on, mediawiki

I am trying to implement an auto login function into my mediawiki by using their windows credentials. I am using Apache Server (V2.2).

I have implemented the Auth remoteuser extension and has implemented the mod_auth_sspi.so in my httpd.conf file and has configure it to be as follows

```
<IfModule !mod_auth_sspi.c>
    LoadModule sspi_auth_module modules/mod_auth_sspi.so
</IfModule>
<Location "file/to/path">
    Options FollowSymLinks
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    AuthName "TestWeb"
    AuthType SSPI 
    SSPIAuth On 
    SSPIAuthoritative On
    SSPIOmitDomain On
    SSPIOfferBasic on
    Require valid-user 
</Location>
```

However, it gives me the prompt to type in the username and password on IE/Firefox/Chrome which I don't want the prompt to appear. I want it to auto login to mediawiki straight without the prompt. Which step am I doing wrong?

How may I achieve the above? Thanks for all assistance!

Comment: nobody knows why ? :(

Comment: You may want to share your experience in https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Requests_for_comment/AuthManager so that such a job is made easier in the future.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using domain login credentials on webpage ? Configuring Mediawiki to do this? Is it possible?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11954817/using-domain-login-credentials-on-webpage-configuring-mediawiki-to-do-this-is)

Answer (score 0):

Remove 'SSPIOfferBasic on' and make sure your IE options are set as described here:

[Single Sign On with apache on windows 7 and mod_auth_sspi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2652108/single-sign-on-with-apache-on-windows-7-and-mod-auth-sspi)

SSPIOfferBasic means "clients, you can authenticate, using basic auth", so most browsers will chose that instead of SSO/NTLM